# Animate between two materials on a mesh Three.js

Tags: three.js, gsap

I am trying to change a Meshes material to another material over time (preferably using Greensock Animation Platform). Is there a way to do this using non shader materials?

pseudo code:

```
TweenMax.to(mesh.material.map, 1, {image:newTexture});
```

Comment: I suggest rendering your texture transition externally into a [Texture Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) (but be aware of your system's `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` value). You can then change the offsets into the atlas at specific keyframes during the transition, giving the appearance that the texture is blending from one into another.

Answer (score 3):

You want to tween from one material to another without writing a custom `ShaderMaterial`.

Here is one way to achieve that effect. It requires duplicating your mesh, though.

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material1 ); // transparent false
scene.add( mesh );

var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 ); // transparent true, opacity 0
scene.add( mesh2 );

//mesh2.onBeforeRender = function ( renderer ) { renderer.clearDepth(); }; // optional

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( mesh2.material )
    .to( { opacity: 1 }, 1500 )
    .delay( 1500 )
    .start();
```

Be sure to call

```
TWEEN.update();
```

in your animation loop.

three.js r.87

Answer (score 1):

You can use `emissiveMap` to store new image and keeping its `color` to `0x000000` initially.

You can then run two tweens.

First to tween the diffuse `map` color from `{r:1, g:1, b:1}` to `{r:0, g:0, b:0}`

And the other tween for changing emissive color from `{r:0, g:0, b:0}` to `{r:1, g:1, b:1}`